# Shopify GraphQL API: Editing an order

Tags: php, api, graphql, shopify

I am trying to edit an already placed order using the Shopify GraphQL APIs.
I am getting valid results for getting the shop information, so there are no issues with connecting to shopify. But while creating the `beginEdit` mutation I am getting the response

**`Field 'orderEditBegin' doesn't exist on type 'Mutation'`.**

The PHP library I have used is [this](https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify), the code used is also based on this library. Credentials used are from a private Shopify app. I have also tried using another [PHP library](https://github.com/ohmybrew/Basic-Shopify-API), but is getting the same response.

Below is what I have tried,

```
$config = array(
   'ShopUrl' => '*******.myshopify.com',
   'ApiKey' => '********************',
   'SharedSecret' => '********************',
   'AccessToken' => '********************'
);

$shopify = PHPShopify\ShopifySDK::config($config);

$graphQL = <<<Query
        mutation beginEdit{
 orderEditBegin(id: "gid://shopify/Order/1234"){
    calculatedOrder{
      id
    }
  }
}
Query;

var_dump($shopify->GraphQL->post($graphQL));
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`orderEditBegin`is currently in the **unstable** version and it's available only on Preview Developer Stores. More info: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/mutation/ordereditbegin

If you are not using such store please use a different GraphQL request.

For example: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/graphql-admin-api/reference/mutation/orderupdate

Comment: I need to add a line item to an order. Don't think that is possible with orderUpdate function. as mentioned in https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-APIs-SDKs/Updating-line-item-properties-of-a-order/m-p/470371#M29778. Is there some way I can achieve this?